# Why isn't the proof obtained using Buss's proof of the derivational completeness of LK anchored?

Tags: lo.logic, proof-complexity, first-order-logic

The version of Buss's proof I'm referring to is the proof of Lemma II.2.24 in *Logical Foundations of Proof Complexity* by Cook and Nguyen. In the interest of keeping this question self-contained I've provided all the particularities of the book in the "Notations, Conventions and Definitions" section at the end of this question.

---

### Background

**Theorem II.2.23:** Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a first-order language which does not contain the equality symbol. Let $\Phi$ be a set of formulas of $\mathcal{L}$, and $\Gamma \rightarrow \Delta$ be a sequent of $\mathcal{L}$. There is an LK-$\Phi$ proof of $\Gamma \rightarrow \Delta$ iff $\forall \Phi \vDash \Gamma \rightarrow \Delta$.

The proof of this theorem relies on the following Lemma.

**Lemma II.2.24:** If $\Phi \vDash \Gamma \rightarrow \Delta$, then there is a cut-free LK proof of $C_1, C_2, ..., C_k, \Gamma \rightarrow \Delta$, where $\{C_i : i \in [k]\}$ is a finite subset of $\Phi$.

My question pertains specifically to the proof of completeness.

**Proof of completeness direction of Theorem II.2.23:** Let $\Phi$ be a set of formulas such that $\forall \Phi \vDash \Gamma \rightarrow \Delta$. By Lemma II.2.24, we know there is finite subset ${C_1,...,C_k}$ of $\Phi$ such that there is an LK proof $\pi$ of $S := \forall C_1, ..., \forall C_k, \Gamma \rightarrow \Delta$. Notice that if we can derive, for any $i \in [k]$, the sequent $\rightarrow \forall C_i$, then we are done: by weakening each such sequent appropriately, we can apply the cut rule to remove $\forall C_i$ from $S$. Applying all such cuts yields an LK-$\Phi$ proof $\pi'$ of the sequent $\Gamma \rightarrow \Delta$.

It remains to show that we can derive $\forall C_i$. Starting from nonlogical axiom $\rightarrow C_i$, we can apply the right $\forall$-introduction rule for each free variable in $C_i$. $\blacksquare$

Note that in $\pi'$ above, we cut on formulas of the form $\forall C_i$. Since $\pi'$ is an LK-$\Phi$ proof and not an LK-$\forall \Phi$ proof, this means that $\pi'$ is not necessarily anchored. However according to the book (assuming certain conditions on $\Phi$), it is possible to show that an anchored LK-$\Phi$ proof of $\Gamma \rightarrow \Delta$ exists. In the book, this is Theorem II.2.28. Proving this theorem is Exercise II.2.29.

---

### My Question

How isn't the following simple modification to the proof above a proof of anchored derivational completeness of LK?

**(Proposed) Proof:** Let $\Phi$ be a set of $\mathcal{L}$-formulas such that $\forall \Phi \vDash S$, where $S := \Gamma \rightarrow \Delta$. By Lemma II.2.24, we know there is finite subset ${C_1,...,C_k}$ of $\Phi$ such that there is a **cut-free** LK proof $\pi$ of $S := C_1, ..., C_k, \Gamma \rightarrow \Delta$. For any $i \in [k]$, by weakening each nonlogical axiom $\rightarrow C_i$ appropriately, we can apply the cut rule to remove $C_i$ from $S$. Applying all such cuts yields an LK-$\Phi$ proof $\pi''$ of the sequent $\Gamma \rightarrow \Delta$.

Since the only cuts in $\pi''$ are on $C_i \in \Phi$, we conclude $\pi''$ is an anchored LK-$\Phi$ proof of $\Gamma \rightarrow \Delta$. $\blacksquare$

---

### Notations, Conventions and Definitions

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a first order language. We define two disjoint, infinite set of variables of $\mathcal{L}$: *free* variables, and *bound* variables. As a convention, in any formula $A$ of $\mathcal{L}$ we require that there are no bound occurrences of free variables and that there are no free occurrences of bound variables in $A$.

We say formula $B$ is a logical consequence of $A$, denoted $A \vDash B$, if for every $\mathcal{L}$-structure $\mathcal{M}$ and every object assignment $\sigma$ from the variables of $L$ to the universe $M$ of $\mathcal{M}$, if $\mathcal{M}$ satisfies $A$ under $\sigma$, denoted $\mathcal{M} \vDash A[\sigma]$, then $\mathcal{M} \vDash B[\sigma]$.

If $\Phi$ is a set of formulas $\{A_i\}$, then we say $\mathcal{M}$ satisfies $\Phi$ under $\sigma$, denoted $\mathcal{M} \vDash \Phi[\sigma]$, if $\mathcal{M} \vDash A_i[\sigma]$ for all $i$. We say $B$ is a logical consequence of $\Phi$, denoted $\Phi \vDash B$, if $\mathcal{M} \vDash \Phi[\sigma]$ implies $\mathcal{M} \vDash B[\sigma]$.

Let $S := \Gamma \rightarrow \Delta$ be a sequent where $\Gamma := \{A_1, ..., A_m\}$ and $\Delta := \{B_1, ..., B_n\}$ are sets of $\mathcal{L}$-formulas. We define $A_S$ as the first order formula

$$\lnot A_1 \lor \lnot A_2 \lor ... \lor \lnot A_m \lor B_1 \lor B_2 \lor ... \lor B_n$$

and we say that $\mathcal{M}$ satsifies $S$ under $\sigma$, denoted $\mathcal{M} \vDash S[\sigma]$, if $\mathcal{M} \vDash A_S[\sigma]$. We say $S$ is a logical consequence of $\Phi$, denoted $\Phi \vDash S$, if $\mathcal{M} \vDash \Phi[\sigma]$ implies $\mathcal{M} \vDash S[\sigma]$.

An LK proof of $S$ is a tree $\pi$ with root is $S$ whose leaves are sequents $A \rightarrow A$ for any formula $A$, $\bot \rightarrow$, or $\rightarrow \top$ (we call these sequents *logical axioms*) and whose internal nodes are sequents such that if node $S'$ has set of children $H$, then $H$ is the set of hypothesis (top) sequents and $S'$ is the conclusion (bottom) sequent of one of the following rules.

[image: PK rules]

[image: LK bonus rules]

where $A(t)$ is the formula obtained by replacing all free occurrences of $x$ in $A(x)$ (i.e. the occurrences of $x$ in $\forall x A(x)$ which become free when we remove the $\forall x$ quantifier), with a term $t$ consisting entirely of free variables. Similarly, $A(b)$ is the formula obtained by replacing all free occurrences of $x$ in $A(x)$ by free variable $b$. In the left $\exists$-introduction and right $\forall$-introduction rules, $b$ must not occur anywhere in the conclusion sequent.

An LK-$\Phi$ proof of $S$ is an LK proof of $S$ in which we allow the leaves to be sequents of the form $\rightarrow A_i$ for $A_i \in \Phi$, which we call *nonlogical axioms*, in addition to the logical axioms.

We say that an LK-$\Phi$ proof is *cut-free* if it does not use the cut rule, and we say that it is *anchored* if the only formulas it cuts appear in $\Phi$.

Note that two rules of $LK$ aren't "sound" in the sense that the conclusion sequent is not a logical consequence of the hypothesis sequent: right $\forall$-introduction and left $\exists$-introduction. As such, it is necessary to tweak the usual definition of soundness a bit in order to speak of the soundness of LK. We do this with the *universal closure*.

The universal closure of $A$, denoted $\forall A$, is the formula $\forall x_1 ... \forall x_k A$, where $x_1, ..., x_k$ are all the free variables of $A$. We define the universal closure of $\Phi$, denoted $\forall \Phi$, as $\{\forall A_i\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer occurred to me right after I finished typing up the post. Rather than delete it, I figured I would post it anyway in case anyone else has the same question.

---

### Answer

The mistake in the proposed proof is that in order to use Lemma II.2.24, I implicitly assume that if $\forall \Phi \vDash S$, then $\Phi \vDash S$. However, this is not necessarily true! Let $P$ be a 1-ary predicate of $\mathcal{L}$, and consider the example of $\Phi := \{P(b)\}$, and $S := \rightarrow \forall x Px$. Clearly $\forall \Phi \vDash S$, but it is not the case that $Pb \vDash \forall xPx$.